# Нет звука на ноутбуке Huawei matebook d15 OS - fedora 37

Tags: linux, fedora

Добрые день.
После установки дистибутива на ноутбуке пропал звук. Ни внутренние динамики, ни наушники, ни блютуз наушники. Звука нигде нет. В устройствах вывода числиться - Фиктивный выход и всё.

Что сделать, чтобы звук появился?

[image: Что показывает neofetch]

Comment: текст приводите текстом, а не картинкой

Answer (score 0):

Звук в последних поколениях ноутов не pnp, висит на отдельной шине.

Автоматом не ставится даже в виндовс.

Чтоб его включить нужно узнать адрес кодека(аппаратный) и прогрузить его в специальный драйвер.

Если в биос есть возможность переключить кодек, то попробуй переключить. Но в новых ноутах уже такой возможности нет.

Попробуй отключить fast boot.

А может быть не хватает firmware.

Выложи dmesg